# Textarea or textbox components is avail in nativescript with angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to get input as paragraph(Like address of user) from the user. For that i am looking for UI component in nativescript. If i use textfield, is there is any characters limit is maintained. Or shall i use textfield in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NativeScript `TextView` is to `TextField` what `textarea` is to `input type="text"` on the web.

Doc link: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#textview

Comment: Thank you @Eddy Verbruggen. I got it. Can you please tell the maximum default characters limit of address field for mobile apps?

Comment: I don't think there's a human-reachable maximum. You can set a maxLength if you like though.